# Perl - assigning a composite string to a variable

Tags: string, perl, assign

I would like to assign the whole string on the right to the variable on the left

```
my $branch =  "\t" x $level, "$level -> $treeRoot\n";
```

Where `$level` is a number and `$treeRoot` is a string. When I try to print `$branch` it says the variable is empty.

An example of what should happen: say `$level` is `5` and `$treeRoot` is `"string"`. I would like `$branch` to take the value of:

```
my $branch = "\t\t\t\t\t5 -> string\n";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
my $branch = "\t" x $level, "$level -> $treeRoot\n";
```

with

```
my $branch = "\t" x $level . "$level -> $treeRoot\n";
```

`.` is the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [the `,` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator):

> Binary "," is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its
>   left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right
>   argument and returns that value. This is just like C's comma operator.

The assignment operator has a higher precedence than the binary comma.  Basically your code is  equivalent to:

```
(my $branch = "\t" x $level), "$level -> $treeRoot\n";
```

Or with the comma operator written out:

```
my $branch = "\t" x $level;
"$level -> $treeRoot\n";
```

First `my $branch = "\t" x $level` is evaluated.  Then, `"$level -> $treeRoot\n"` is evaluated.  But it's a string in a void context.

To explore this some more, if you put parenthesis around the right hand side:

```
my $branch =  ("\t" x $level, "$level -> $treeRoot\n");
```

Now the assignment itself is no longer part of the left-hand side of the comma operator.  The `$branch` variable is assigned `"$level -> $treeRoot\n"`, or the right-hand of the comma operator.

If you change the comma operator to `.`, the string concatenation operator:

```
my $branch = "\t" x $level . "$level -> $treeRoot\n";
```

your code will work as expected.

P.S.  If you add If you add:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of your file, Perl will give you a warning that something is not right:

```
Useless use of string in void context
```

It's usually a good idea to have `strict` and `warnings` enabled.